# What is the right way to write a .desktop file to launch app with a specific theme on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gtk, .desktop

My system is Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to start corebird with a specific theme from a `.desktop` file.
So I created a `.desktop` file with this exec line:

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=mytheme corebird
```

But corebird launched with the gnome-shell default theme.

Then I created a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export GTK_THEME="mytheme" 

exec /usr/bin/corebird "$@"
```

... and change exec line with:

```
Exec=/home/me/bin/corebird.sh
```

... but same result, corebird launched with GNOME default theme.

So, what is the way to launch an app with specific theme from a `.desktop` file ?

Comment: Does running `GTK_THEME=mytheme corebird` in Terminal work? Also how did you install corebird?

Comment: @pomsky, yes it works, and launch the script from command line works too... corebird was installed with apt.

Answer (score 2):

In your desktop file, change the exec line to

```
Exec=sh -c "GTK_THEME=mytheme corebird"
```

Alternatively, if you work with the wrapper script, change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
GTK_THEME="mytheme" /usr/bin/corebird "$@"
```

Beware that this approach to apply a different theme will work only with GTK3 applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vanadium, but your changes have no effects.

Comment: Before posting this answer, I have tested myself with gedit. Perhaps corebird is a GTK2 application. This approach only works with GTK3 applications. I will add that to the answer. Obviously, that is the approach you asked to get working, so strictly speaking, this is the answer to the question as you asked it.

Comment: yes effectively, you are right. I should have written all the .desktop file in my question... So... Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the environment variable theme is not enabled, is caused by this line in .destop file:

```
DBusActivatable=true
```

As explained in [freedesktop.org specifications](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html):

> A boolean value specifying if D-Bus activation is supported for this
>   application. If this key is missing, the default value is false. If
>   the value is true then implementations should ignore the Exec key and
>   send a D-Bus message to launch the application. See D-Bus Activation
>   for more information on how this works. Applications should still
>   include Exec= lines in their desktop files for compatibility with
>   implementations that do not understand the DBusActivatable key.

So, putting this value to false or deleting this line fixes this issue:

```
DBusActivatable=false
```